# Нужно закрыть выпадающий список при клике на label

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу написать код для закрытия списка. Сделал, чтобы он закрывался при клике в любое другое пространство, но не могу сделать закрытие при клике на label.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    const click = e.composedPath().includes(label)
    
    if (!click){
        list.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
        list.style.display = "block";
        on = true;
        console.log(on);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто проверяйте, что если нажатие было по `label` и при этом список показан (`display: block;`), тогда вы его скрываете (`display: none;`).

Вот пример кода:

```js
const label = document.querySelector('.label');
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    const click = e.composedPath().includes(label);
    if (!click || (click && list.style.display=="block")){
        list.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        list.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class='label'>Click</label>
<div class='list'>List</div>
```